# Need Facebook to stay logged in for Corporate Account

Tags: facebook, token, facebook-authentication, facebook-login

We have a Facebook App and for the most part it works well.  It connects to our CMS and our customers can post Facebook posts from the CMS directly to Facebook.  The idea here is that any employee can post to the company page in Facebook.   Our CMS has a built in approval process where the manager of the company can approve or deny the Facebook post.  The idea is that nobody has the username or password to the Corporate Facebook account.  With that being said we want the CMS itself to always be logged into Facebook so that when approvals take place they get sent to Facebook.

Our Problem:  The CMS only stays connected for the life of the Token, 2hrs.  This defeats the purpose of having corporate social media workflow.  We don't want a Facebook prompt to pop up for any employees, they will not know the password to post to Facebook. That's the idea.

Our Question: How can we make it so that the CMS always has access to post. It seems like OpenAuth does not work for our scenario.  Is there a way to directly authenticate with the CMS rather than trying to deal with timeout tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Re-read the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation and specifically the flow for page management which I assume is what you're doing with the token - provided you retrieve a 60 day (long-expiry) token from the Server-Side Oauth flow, the Page Access Token you retrieve for managing your company's Facebook page will be infinite and won't expire.

This is further explained under Scenario 5 on the [offline access removal](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) document

Comment: Ok Great.  I will look at that and see if that is what I need.